# Android Market developer groups

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying here to find a way to give access to other people to my market publisher account so that another person can push updates or modify things when he wants, but without giving away my password, I know that on AppStore you can do that, but can you do it on Android Market?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. Publisher accounts can, for now, only have a single login. There are [various threads](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=327297c08485a353&hl=en) in the support forums bemoaning this unfortunate fact.